# Swift-addConstraint : Cannot convert expression's type (constraint: [AnyObject])' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm using constraintsWithVisualFormat in addConstraint to create custom header but I got:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83beY.png]

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`headerLabel.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[headerLabel]-0-|", options: 0, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))`

Instead.

`addConstraint()` takes only 1 constraint, but `NSLayoutConstraints.constraintsWithVisualFormat()` returns an array of constraints.